# Sample sizes in neural networks

Tags: neural-network

I've seen that the general rule of sample sizes in neural networks is 10 times the 'number of weights'.  So for example, if we have a NxD input, one layer size M, and output layer size K, is the 'number of weights' 2 because of the two W matrices?  Or is it D*M + M*K?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Sadly there is no general rule and it always depends on the data too. Use cross-validation to evaluate your network, everything else is guessing (yeah of course some people got so much experience that they are a bit better at this guessing game).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual number of weights should be `DM + MK + M + K` where `DM` represents the number of weights for all unit in the hidden layer and `M` is for the bias terms in the hidden layer and in the same way, `MK` and `K` represent number of wights and bias terms in the output layer respectively.